# how to create multiple pages in html

Tags: html, css

Can someone please inform me the code to create multiple webpages in HTML? I have the homepage completely finished, however I do not know how I can branch off from there and create webpages. Thanksya!

Comment: You mean you want move from home page to another pages?

Comment: i think you should [visit the school please](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a new page in another file in the same directory, `new_page.html`. If you want to be able to go to that page from your homepage, add a link in the body like

```
<a href="./new_page.html">Link text here</a>
```

Comment: I'm using the program 'Brackets', and It won't let me rename a file

Comment: You don't need to rename a file. Create a new file called `new_page.html`. You should then be able to open it in Brackets.